TypeScript update with Angular update from 16 to 17
I'm trying to upgrade Angular from 16 to 17. The upgrade guide says:

Make sure that you are using a supported version of TypeScript before you upgrade your application. Angular v17 supports TypeScript version 5.2 or later.

However, Angular 16 requires TypeScript >=4.9.3 <5.2 and if I run npm install -D typescript@5.2 trying to install TypeScript 5.2 or later I get the error:
npm warn Could not resolve dependency:
npm warn peer typescript@">=4.9.3 <5.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.12

Therefore, TypeScript upgrade fails because Angular 16 doesn't support it. If I stay in my current TypeScript version and run ng update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17 I get the following error:
Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=4.9.3 <5.2", would install "5.4.5").
✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.

How do I get out of this situation?

Definitely looks like misinformation in the update guide. You should not update your TypeScript version before the update. You should stay on the current TypeScript version and run ng update, the TypeScript version should be automatically updated.

Thanks for the suggestion. I think there's a misunderstanding and edit my question accordingly: "If I stay in my current TypeScript version and run ng update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17 I get the following error..."

The problem might be that you are trying to perform the update with the latest Angular CLI version. Try to use v17 instead:
npx @angular/cli@17 update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17


Do you know why this is not in the Update Guide?

IIRC it used to be like this in the update guide. I have no idea why this is not the case anymore.

This worked, and updated typescript as well. It didn't update @angular/cdk": "16.2.12".

For CDK, you need to include @angular/cdk@17 to the command, or @angular/material@17 if your project uses Angular Material.

Incompatible peer dependencies occured for me as well, though in a slightly different scenario. How to resolve Angular update issue Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.11 Maybe this helps?
There is a suggestion to allow legacy-peer-deps in your .nmprc, but for me, that didn't do the trick. However, using --force on the ng update command did (given that I was sure the update should be successful).

This is how I solved the issue:

Manually change typescript in package.json devDependencies: "typescript": "5.2.2" without running npm install
Run ng update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17

This way the upgrade was successful and there were no conflicting dependencies.
I avoid using npx to not depend on yet another library, and I also avoid using --legacy-peer-deps flag with npm because is a sign of incompatible dependencies.

Good that you found a solution which works for you. However I have to disagree to the point that npx should be avoided because it's "yet another library". npx is developed by npm and shipped together with npm, so you don't have to install anything or use any third-party tool. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npx
